# How do I send an event to a Kafka topic from Jhipster Angular frontend?

Tags: angular, apache-kafka, jhipster

I need to send a JSON event to my Kafka topic from a Jhipster Angular frontend. How should I go about doing this? I have no experience using Angular and no experience using REST API's. I have my REST API endpoint to my Kafka cluster which I think I should use somehow.

Answer (score 0):

> I have no experience using Angular and no experience using REST API's

You're going to need experience with these to continue. You can refer to the Kafka REST Proxy documentation, or you can write your own API, then consult the relevant [HTTP-client methods in Angular](https://angular.io/guide/http) to create the necessary requests to send data to your API.